# Assumed 'boolean' error in Config.php

Tags: error, core

I turned on my error log tonight to try to pinpoint what might be dragging down my website. I literally turned it on for 10 seconds then shut it off. In that span, I got the following error 44 times!

```
ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant boolean - assumed 'boolean'  in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1348
```

I checked the Config.php file and matched it up to a Config.php file from a fresh Magento installation and found no variations. The files were identical, so I'm not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 1):

The error seams to appear in the factory method `getModelInstance` (on line `$obj = new $className($constructArguments);`).
This means you are trying to instantiate a model and something is not right.
Unfortunately there is no easy way to pinpoint the problem since this method is called basically from anywhere.
I would start debugging, by logging all variables on that line.
It could be a faulty 3rd party extension or a wrong source model for a product or category or customer attribute.
Or it could be an other reason, but I would start with these 2.
Actually, the first thing you should check is the `eav_attribute` table for a record with `source_model` = 'boolean' or `frontend_model` = 'boolean'.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I checked eav_attribute and currently the only item that has 'boolean' as a frontend_model is disable_auto_group_change. There's 8 items however that include 'boolean' in the source_model, however it's listed as eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean.